# How to pass parameters to a function when using React stateless components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component like this (very simplified version)

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const handleClick = param => {
      console.log(param);
  }

  return (
     <Link to={'/'} onClick={handleClick} value={'a string'}>
  );

}
```

How can I pass a parameter to the handleClick function?

Comment: use a callback: `onClick={() => func(myArgs)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass a function to `onClick`. onClick will always call your functions with an `event` parameter. So if you pass a function like this:

```
onClick={handleClick}
```

It will be called like this:

```
onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}
```

So to pass parameters to a function you can do something like this instead:

```
onClick={() => handleClick(parameters)}
```